# how can I achieve this with css?

Tags: html, css

I'm not really a front-end guy but I'm trying to learn. I got this psd from my designer and I'm wondering what is the best way to write the styles and markup for this small tab at the front of the menu item.

[image]

I've started building everything else using bootstrap but here's what I have for the menus so far.

Thanks Again For Your Help

```
.sideMenu {
    width: 230px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.sideMenu > li {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-indent: 25px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E6EF;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    /* Chrome transition flicker & double border fix */
    -webkit-transition: height .2s ease;
        -moz-transition: height .2s ease;
            transition: height .2s ease;
}

.sideMenu > li.open {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
    /* Chrome transition flicker & double border fix */
    -webkit-transition: height .4s ease;
        -moz-transition: height .4s ease;
            transition: height .4s ease;
}

.sideMenu > li.active {
    background-color: #E5E9EA;
    color: #6E787E;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-top: 1px solid #E1E6EF;
}


.sideMenu > li > a {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Can't you just put a `border-left` on it?

Comment: yes as rudeovski ze bear suggested below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a basic example.

CSS:

```
.menu { width: 300px; border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; margin:0; padding:0 }
.menu-item { border-left:5px solid #fff; border-top: 1px solid #ddd; color:#666; list-style:none; padding:5px; }
.menu-item:hover { border-left:5px solid #ddd; background: #eee; }
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="menu-item">Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G2fcY/

TL;DR: Use borders to get the 'blue tab' thing you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks so much, that works perfectly. I'll accept your answer as soon as the timer allows me ^^

Comment: If I wanted to append a separate selector for each item the correct syntax would be this correct?

.sideMenu .dashboard > li.active {
    border-left: 6px solid #6E787E;
}

where .dashboard is the selector

Comment: nevermind, i solved it. Thanks anyways, it's .sideMenu > li.active, .dashboard > li.active ~